# Magnific Pop-up image too big

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

I'm having some trouble with a content that I had someone build for me on wordpress. Of course they took their money and ran so I can't quite figure out what is happening.
On desktop, it seems to be fine, however on mobile, this Magnific Popup isn't working right. It displays the image at it's full width instead of being responsive to the screen size. I don't want to make the image itself smaller because then it will be small on desktop. 
This is the code I have for it when I inspect it on chrome:

```
         <div class="mfp-content"><div class="mfp-iframe-scaler"><button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button><iframe class="mfp-iframe" src="test.jpg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div></div>
#document
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1"><title>test.jpg (900×506)</title></head><body style="margin: 0px;"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="test.jpg"></body></html>
```

however the actual source code says:

```
 <div class="attribute-media-wrap">
                                        <a href="test.jpg" class="vedio_wrap">
                                            <img src="test.png">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="attribute-media-title-desc">

                                        </div>
```

I have tried multiple ways to try and call out that image but I can't add a class to it since I can't edit that code.

Comment: Did you try just attaching a style to the element instead? Adding a style instead of class to either the div or the actual imgag tag might work around their styling. Not the cleanest though, as you'll have two css statements arguing against each other.

Comment: I can't add anything to the html itself because I don't have the access to it with WordPress. I can add custom css or mess around with a php file and I don't even know where to begin with that

Comment: If you can mess ness with their css, have you tried locating "mfp-content" or "attribute-media-wrap"? I'd think you could just add something on to the end of the prexisting classes.

Comment: I've tried to add css to say something like .mfp-content img {width:100%:} and it doesn't change anything. I've even tried calling out the image with css selectors targeting the specific url and that's not changing anything with.

Comment: I can use the inspector stylesheet and that makes it do what I want but adding the same code into a code block on the page or into my custom css file and nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

The content of the popup is an iframe.

The markup for this popup is most likely set in your main javascript file. See an example of this implementation in the [magnific popup documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#iframe-type).

To style this in css you would need to target the iframe itself, not the contents of the iframe. i.e:

```
.mfp-iframe {max-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: The image itself is the problem, not the iframe. The iframe appears normal on both mobile and desktop. The image, does not. It should be responsive with the iframe, however, the image stays at it's normal size. So when you skrink the page down, once it gets to a certain size, scroll bars appear and the image does not shrink. On mobile, the image doesn't have scroll bars it just takes up the while screen. So this code is already in place and does not change what I need.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this is set up as an iframe type pop-up as opposed to an image type? Is the image served from your own domain?

Comment: It is an image that we uploaded to wordpress, yes. I did not write the code for this image pop up, so I can not access it either.